# Rendering integers to a separate texture in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I want to render a set of textured quads in OpenGL, but I was wondering if there was any way to pass in a unique integer id with each quad to the shader pipeline?

The id needs to be available to the fragment shader so that it can be rendered to a texture, separately from the rest of the image, because I want to reference the texture later to find out what id is at what location on the screen.

Comment: How many quads are you talking here? There is `gl_PrimitiveID` available in the fragment stage, but if you draw more than 256 quads (or 128 if each one is broken into two triangles) you will overflow a general (8-bit) single-channel image format. So then you would have to encode your ID across multiple channels; not terribly difficult, but you might be better off using a single-channel 16-/32-bit integer texture at that point.

Comment: I'll probably have quite a few, as I'll be using the system for an isometric game, and intend to use it for movement, attacking enemies, picking up items, moving through doors, etc. I think I'd prefer the option of a 32-bit integer texture, to reduce the likelihood of having any clashes, especially as I want to use the high-order byte as a flag for the type of object at that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tack on another vertex attribute for the ID and pass that through to your fragment shader.

You can set up [Multiple Render Targets (MRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207422/setting-up-opengl-multiple-render-targets) to render your IDs out to another framebuffer attachment.

Comment: Seems a bit wasteful memory wise. `gl_PrimitiveID` would do the same thing without adding an extra vertex attribute.