# How to use two different colour buffers at any given time

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there a way to use two different colour buffers, such that one will be used to draw on the screen, while the other one will be used for some other purpose. For example, one buffer will be drawn on the screen, while on the other buffer I will perform some Accumulation function. The buffers shouldn't have any connection at all, and both can read or written to at any given time.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know about framebuffers? (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up OpenGL Multiple Render Targets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207422/setting-up-opengl-multiple-render-targets)

Comment: FBO doesn't allow one to draw to both buffers at the same time, so that only one of them will affect the screen.